# Java Regular Expression on a .txt file

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I want to scan a txt file to find paths. So my regex is `"[A-Z]:\\"`
I'm not sure how to feed my file into the expression. `Pattern.matcher()` needs a char sequence. So what I have in mind is to either [convert my file to a character sequence](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/37-java-util-regex/1716-how-to-apply-regular-expressions-on-the-contents-of-a-file.html), or take each line of the file and convert it to a string and feed each string into `Pattern.matcher()`. The latter option would be much slower because it makes a new matcher for each line. Right?

Comment: could you reduce your question to one single question? But if you have "line of the file" that is typically already a string, and since you can reuse the same pattern, a new matcher for each line is not very costly - it's creating the pattern that is costly. A character sequence in java is typically just a string.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't bother with the solution proposed in the link unless you expect the file to be really large. The solution uses `FileChannel` under the hood, and according to its javadocs:

> For most operating systems, mapping a file into memory is more expensive than reading or writing a few tens of kilobytes of data via the usual read and write methods. From the standpoint of performance it is generally only worth mapping relatively large files into memory.

If the file is relatively small and your paths cannot span multiple lines, which seems to be the case, I would go for [Files.lines(Path path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: The file is very small. I just don't want to teach myself the wrong way to do things. `Files.lines` returns a stream. Do you have any good links to where I can learn how streams work, what they are made of, how do I isolate just one part of a steam? How would I implement this in terms of pattern and matcher? Thanks